# HTTP Negotiate windows vs. Unix server implementation using python-kerberos

Tags: python, kerberos

I tried to implement a simple single-sign-on in my python web server. I have used the python-kerberos package which works nicely. I have tested it from my Linux box (authenticating against active directory) and it was without problem.
However, when I tried to authenticate using Firefox from Windows machine (no special setup, just having the user logged into the domain + added my server into negotiate-auth.trusted-uris), it doesn't work. I have looked at what is sent and it doesn't even resemble the things the Linux machine sends. This [Microsoft description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995330.aspx) of the process pretty much resembles the way my interaction from Linux works, but the Windows machine generally sends a very short string, which doesn't even resemble the things microsoft documentation states, and when base64 decoded, it is something like 12 zero bytes followed by 3 or 4 non-zero bytes (GSS functions then return that it doesn't support such scheme)

Either there is something wrong with the client Firefox settings, or there is some protocol which I am supposed to follow for the Negotiate protocol, but which I cannot find any reference anywhere. Any ideas what's wrong? Do you have any idea what protocol I should by trying to find, as it doesn' look like SPNEGO, at least from MS documentation.

Update: now it seems to at least produce reasonable data (clean installation of firefox on something different than windows7...), however I am getting:
(('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('', 100004))
The Negotiate data now seems to be OK, so this is some other error. Any idea where can I decode what 100004 means?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you also need to make sure that *network.auth.use-sspi = true*, so that Firefox will use the native Windows Kerberos (SSPI) rather than look for a GSSAPI DLL.

If that's not it, and you want to provide a packet capture of the Kerberos and HTTP traffic, I'm happy to look at it.